# Как вытащить данные из массива с объекта?

Tags: php, массивы, битрикс

Есть такой массив

```
    Bitrix\Sale\BasketItem Object
(
    [fields:protected] => Bitrix\Sale\Internals\Fields Object
        (
            [values:protected] => Array
                (
                    [MODULE] => catalog
                    [BASE_PRICE] => 3000
                    [CAN_BUY] => Y
                    [VAT_RATE] => 0.2
                    [CUSTOM_PRICE] => N
                    [PRODUCT_ID] => 1141
                    [XML_ID] => bx_65292dd24002e
                    [LID] => s1
                    [SORT] => 100
                    [CURRENCY] => RUB
                    [PRODUCT_PROVIDER_CLASS] => \Bitrix\Catalog\Product\CatalogProvider
                    [NAME] => Подарочный сертификат на 3000 рублей
                    [PRICE] => 3000
                    [QUANTITY] => 1
                    [VAT_INCLUDED] => Y
                    [PRODUCT_PRICE_ID] => 4105
                    [NOTES] => Обмен с сайтом
                    [PRICE_TYPE_ID] => 2
                    [DISCOUNT_PRICE] => 0
                    [CATALOG_XML_ID] => --d7c023e0-e1d6-46d6-912e-e4e916eac43b
                    [PRODUCT_XML_ID] => bc764f21-b73f-11ec-86f4-ac1f6badceb9
                    [DETAIL_PAGE_URL] => 
                    [MEASURE_NAME] => шт
                    [MEASURE_CODE] => 796
                    [BARCODE_MULTI] => N
                    [WEIGHT] => 0
                    [DIMENSIONS] => a:3:{s:5:"WIDTH";N;s:6:"HEIGHT";N;s:6:"LENGTH";N;}
                )
```

Как мне вытащить данные из массива со значением ["PRICE"] ?

Comment: Тут же прям черным по белому написано - `Object`.

Comment: Беглый поиск показывает что https://mrcappuccino.ru/blog/post/work-with-basket-bitrix-d7

Comment: Точно , спасибо! Вопрос закрыт